# XeLaTeX: Counters not working correctly with expex

Tags: xetex, counters, expex

I'm using `expex` for glossing translations of foreign languages. I want to label certain words in the gloss which I want to explain later with numbers in superscripts. Then I plan to use `enumerate` to make an ordered list of explanations, each of which correspond to a labelled word.

I created a counter (`\newcounter{counter}`) and set the value to 1 (`\setcounter{counter}{1}`). I label a word with `\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}` then increment the counter with `\stepcounter{counter}`. I also remembered to increment the counter immediately after labeling: `\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter}` without any spaces in between, because the glossing environment provided by `expex` recognizes any spaces in LaTeX code as delimiters separating one word from another.

I expect the counter to increment every time I use it to label a word. I will also use the counter throughout the document. Unfortunately my code did not work.

I prepared the following MWE code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{expex}

\newcounter{counter}

\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Chapter}

    \section{Section}

    \setcounter{counter}{1}

    Hello\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter} there.

    I am bleeding\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter}.

    \pex
    \begingl
        \gla Hann var kalladr\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter} Kormakr //
        \glb he was called Kormak\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter} //
        \glft He was\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter} called Kormak. //
    \endgl
    \xe

    The future\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter} is now\textsuperscript{\arabic{counter}}\stepcounter{counter}.

\end{document}
```

This results in.

[image]

The numbering goes 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 which I would expect. This is a problem as I will use the same counter throughout the document; the numbering will increment irregularly.

Is my code wrong? What should I do?

Comment: It seems that the text of the `\gla` part is processed three times.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `xelatex` but is 'design' problem of `expex`. Perhaps it's possible to query about the value of `\@glsparsestate` count register